# Compare and count values in mysql rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
upVote   DownVote
|true   | 0
|true   | 0
|0      | true
|true   | 0
|true   | 0
|0      | true
```

I have columns like this above in my sql table. I want to count the total number of upVotes - Downvotes just like stackOverflow. But for some reason I am having hard time with sql syntax.

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(CASE WHEN upvote THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) from Ratings WHERE TopicID = :topicsID
```

I have seen the above sql query example somewhere but not sure I am heading in the right direction.Help is appreciated

Comment: What is the issue with your query?  Your on the right track, but clearly only counting upvotes.

Comment: Can you ever have `true | true` or `false | false` ?

Comment: Since MySQL booleans are integers, simply use `SUM(upVote)`

Comment: @GordonLinoff with the above query not sure if it's implementing the right logic which I need ?

Comment: @Strawberry my bad if it's true in one column then it will be 0 in the another

Comment: I had made changes in my question

Comment: IMHO the table's structure is a little bit meeh... One `upvote` column with a boolean value is enough.

Comment: @MehdiBounya but then how would you compare the down vote . Suppose if there is a downvote the count should also be decrease

Comment: What do you mean by compare the downvote, you can count all upvotes, then count all downvotes.

Comment: @samscoot You're not thinking clearly.

Comment: @samscoot you don't have a problem with the query, you have a problem with your logic. Consider the structure I suggested then update your question when you have a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need to subtract on `sum(upvote)` and `sum(DownVote)`

```
SELECT sum(upvote) - sum(DownVote)
from Ratings 
WHERE TopicID = :topicsID
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1644c/8

I think One `vote` column with a boolean value is enough.

Because True can mean `upvote`,False can mean `DownVote`

```
CREATE TABLE Ratings
(
    Vote BOOL
);
INSERT INTO Ratings VALUES 
(TRUE),
(TRUE),
(0),
(0),
(TRUE),
(TRUE),
(0);

SELECT sum(CASE WHEN Vote THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 
   sum(CASE WHEN Vote THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as vote
from Ratings 
WHERE TopicID = :topicsID
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/727c2b/3

Comment: I edited this to remove the blockquotes (along with other answers of yours containing them). Those have a special use and not to be used as a personal formatting preference. This matter has been discussed on meta a few times. So, can you please stop using those?

Answer (score 0):

```
select COUNT(*) from ratings WHERE upvote=true AND TopicID = :topicsID ?
```

Comment: but how would I compare and decrease the count when there is a downVote?

Comment: didnt know thats what you were aiming for but you could run the same query for false and then subtract true-false